# Crosstab Export with XSLT/XML to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, filemaker

I have a found set in FileMaker that i want to export to Excel in crosstab view with each row represented by a Client, each column represented by a Food, and each value containing the Portion for the specific Client/Food. Something a little like this:

```
ClientNames   FoodName01  FoodName02  FoodName03 FoodName04  ...
ClientName01      10          20                     30
ClientName02      40          50          60         
...
Totals            50          70          60         30  ...
```

As an XLST newbie, I've been doing some search and reading but I stuck on the Grouping and Munchian Method.
Can you point me, in the right direction to get started trying to make this work?

Thanks,

Recep

SAMPLE DATA WITHOUT XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="01-22-2016" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 14.0.5"/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="D.m.yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="TestDB.fmp12" RECORDS="3294" TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
<METADATA>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Food" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Position" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Client" TYPE="TEXT"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Plate" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Portion" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="3294">

<ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="1">
<COL><DATA>EZOGELİN ÇORBA/</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>1580</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>ALTINBAŞ NURUOSMANİYE</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>5</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>70</DATA></COL>
</ROW>

<ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="2">
<COL><DATA>ETLİ NOHUT/</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>1581</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>ALTINBAŞ NURUOSMANİYE</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>5</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>35</DATA></COL>
</ROW>

<ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="3">
<COL><DATA>TAVUKLU YAZ TÜRLÜSÜ/</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>1582,5</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>ALTINBAŞ NURUOSMANİYE</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>5</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>40</DATA></COL>
</ROW>

<!-- RESULTS REMOVED -->
```

Comment: Munchian Method is the right direction. Alternatively, you can use ExecuteSQL or a script to get your grouped report data in FileMaker, create and populate a report table and export that with a simple xslt.

Comment: in originality, this report is creating with Virtual List Technique. But my data set is heavy and ExecuteSQL is slow with sub-queries. This is why i want to use XML/XSLT instead of VL Technique.. Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough info in your question to help you. E.g. is the ClientNames/FoodName01/portion combination is unique or have to be combined? Is Food names a defined list or have to be derived from data?

Comment: Added Totals but stil have problem with Portions. [Files..](https://alametifarika.wetransfer.com/downloads/4104f2eeeee2dd3f11fc9674dcb6d69020160830150529/f6cf12)

Comment: Are the portions combined from different records or you will only have one record for particular food and company?

Comment: Yes Portion, Company and Food are in the same record.

Comment: Nicolai, can you download the files?

Comment: I can, just trying to fin the time to go over your code. I have a feeling, you do not need Munchian Method as you probably need to pivot, not group your results.

Comment: Thanks. Whenever you free...

Comment: Nicolai, I'm still waiting. :)